# UserControl events not triggered

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm working on a semi-professional project and needed a custom view for one of my models. As far as I could figure out that meant creating a UserControl-inherited class, like so:

```
public partial class PopulationView : UserControl
{
    ...
}
```

Now this works wonders, and I've been able to do pretty much all I wanted, including custom painting with onPaint but I've noticed none of the events seem to be registering. I've had to attach multiple event listeners and in all instances I end up going back to my form and adding an event listener to my custom component's instance in the form. For example, I'd like to add a Click event listener. What I try first is simply

```
public partial class PopulationView : UserControl
{
    private void PopulationView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debugger.Break();
    }
}
```

of course attaching the function to the Click event through **PopulationView.cs [Design]**. That doesn't work so I end up adding a Click event listener on the instance of the component and adding the `PopulationView_Click` function to my form (**MainForm.cs [Design]**) instead and launching the appropriate function on the control.

I feel that I'm missing something very simple which is preventing me from being able to register events in my control directly and I'd appreciate any help with this. I dug around the interwebs but couldn't find anything relevant.

**Update**

Some of the comment make me think I should provide more detailed information about what I'm doing. The setup is sort of complicated but here's a summary:

I have a custom control inheriting from UserControl, called PopulationView

I have an instance of that control added to a form

Attaching event listeners through the design view of the form to the instance of the control (listener in form itself) works. Adding them through PopulationView's design view (listener in PopulationView) does not.

What complicates thing is I have a BackgroundWorker in my form which is in charge of generating the PopulationModel for the PopulationView. Once that BackgroundWorker is done, it uses a BeginInvoke to tell the PopulationView it's time to draw.

However, all events behave the way described even before the BackgroundWorker is triggered with RunWorkerAsync. Is it possible it's still interfering?

Comment: Where are you actually clinking? In user control area or some other child control in it?

Comment: Try adding `this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.StandardClick, true);` to the constructor if you are clicking the control itself. If you are clicking other items in the control, they are handling the click themselves and you'll have to add event handlers for the items in the control.

Comment: I'm clicking on the control area itself (it's basically a large graphics area) and adding the click listener to the form's instance of the control works just fine - adding it to the control through its design view doesn't. The SetStyle didn't help either.

Comment: This is more of a side note, but why would you want to grab clicks in particular? It's not really all that useful outside of controls that are specifically "button-like". The usual way of intercepting events in user controls is by overriding the relevant `OnXXX` methods, rather than just adding event handlers. But the event handlers really should still work, so there's probably something weird you're doing as well.

Comment: @Luaan - yes, I feel I'm doing something weird for this not to work and that's why I'm asking. I have one big area in which I draw a bunch of things and I'd like to respond to a click to figure out the coordinates of the click and change the view based on that. I could use child controls but it's not complicated enough to justify I think. I'm inheriting from UserControl so addding onClick doesn't seem to do anything (nothing to override I guess?)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I expected. You don't really want to use the `Click` event for that (after all, they don't carry the position information you need :)). Instead, you'll have to work with `MouseDown` and `MouseUp`. Or, if it's available, `MouseClick`. `Click` is really a bit different, dealing with focus and keyboard control and similar. That said, `Click` works just fine for me, so you're probably doing something that causes you to lose focus or something like that. Or you didn't actually subscribe to the event. You're not showing that code, so it's hard to tell.

Comment: Hm, didn't know that, thanks - switched to MouseClick. Still same behavior though. Added through the custom component's own design view - nothing. Added to the form's instance of the custom view - works.

Comment: You have to think about ZLevels.  In essence..."What are you clicking on?"  I have run into this issue before myself.  If having the click event registered to the form works, but to the control doesn't...then when you click, you are clicking the form, not the control.

For my own work, I never use the designer (gui) to add events.  I always go into the partial class (xyz.designer.cs) and manually register the event by writing it in place.  Mostly because I dont trust the designer.

Comment: @Nevyn - I'm actually adding the listener to the control itself, it's just handled by the form - exact code is `this.populationView.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.populationView_MouseClick);` (Grabbed from designer-generated code). I don't think it's a z issue, clicking outside the control doesn't trigger the listener.

Answer (score 0):

Editing the PopulationView constructor, I had accidentally deleted the call to InitializeComponent(), where all the Designer code was. Silly, really. If you're ever using the Designer, make sure you call InitializeComponent from your constructor.